# php passing garbage values to url in form when used arabic language

Tags: php

i have a simple form designed in html with uses get function it has text box and a button and i supposed to read the content of of input text filed when user presses form

its like this

```
<form name="input" action="searchquery.php" method="get">
                            <input type="text" class="textbox" name="query" value="Search:" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}">
                            <input type="submit" value="" />
```

and i am reading value using php get to read

when i type quran in and press search button its appending url properly `http://localhost/testapps/smartphone/searchquery.php?query=quran like this but when i type same` in arabic القرآن الكريم

its appending something with lots of garbage value do i need to put any special things for using arabic language

```
http://localhost/testapps/smartphone/searchquery.php?query=%26%231575%3B%26%231604%3B%26%231602%3B%26%231585%3B%26%231570%3B%26%231606%3B+%26%231575%3B%26%231604%3B%26%231603%3B%26%231585%3B%26%231610%3B%26%231605%3B
```

Comment: is it the unicode representation of the string you typed?

Comment: then what should i do if i want some thing like this localhost/searchquery.php?query=القرآن%20الكريم

Comment: can any one help on this

Comment: have you tried just decoding the value you get?

Comment: i am not able to add answer<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

 use this code and your done add it to your html page your generating and your problem will be solved

Comment: thanks sevenseacat i got the answer i just added above said meta in head and its working as normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First search and then post questions.. See this 
  [Arabic Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909748/retrieving-arabic-text-from-edittext-in-android/26909909?noredirect=1#comment42371913_26909909)

it helps you...

Comment: i have added the answer in comment section with header too you too read comments before posting answer . i have searched and didnt understand or find it any how i am accepting this answers cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

use this code and your done add it to your html page your generating and your problem will be solved